# React-Native render a horizontal List that have 2 rows

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to implement a List that have 2 rows and I can scroll horizontally and show more (two rows)

Just like this image:
[image]

I have an array with these Items, but I can't figure out how to do that in flatlist since we render one item only at once. Also, is there any component if flatlist or scrollList can't be applied ?

Comment: Just to understand better your list is ? [[], [], [], ]

Comment: Do they scroll individually or together? What exactly is your desired outcome and what have you tried?

Comment: @MuniKumarGundu no my list is a normal list with object for each item -> [{ }, { }, ...]

Comment: @windowsill I want if I scroll one top or down to all scroll. And when I click on one it opens the category page. What I have tried is a normal flatList

Comment: @SDB_1998, did you try my answer?

Comment: Hey @MuniKumarGundu, I tried it but the items are not showing for some reason. I console logged and the renderItem is calling. So, must be a styling problem

Comment: @SDB_1998
Please refer this
 https://snack.expo.dev/MGmPC7ild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only a single list and need to show 2 rows

```
<ScrollView
          horizontal
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
          <FlatList
            scrollEnabled={false}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              alignSelf: 'flex-start',
            }}
            numColumns={Math.ceil(list.length / 2)}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={list}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            //your image code 
        }}
          />
</ScrollView>
```

[Snack URL](https://snack.expo.dev/MGmPC7ild)